# snackbar.show() is not working in setAction

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar

```
snackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(),"Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   snackbar.show();
                }
            });
```

on `OnClick` of **Retry** action I want to again show the same Snackbar.But it is not working!!

Comment: how do you think it will work /

Comment: How to again show the same snackbar onClick of Retry??

Comment: first time how you are showing ?

Comment: Im showing that in different function. I declared the snackbar globally.

Comment: what happens when you click on the retry button ?

Comment: It got dismissed, snackbar.show() is not working inside the retry button.

Comment: @VenkateswaranBalasubramanian, check the answer man

Comment: there is an issue reported. please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `snackbar.show();` outside of `onClick` like below.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
    .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });


View sbView = snackbar.getView();
TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(),"Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo connection = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (connection != null && connection.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
               snackbar.dismiss();
            }
             else{
                snackbar.show();
            }
            }
            });
            snackbar.show(); //add here to show snackbar
```

Comment: Im doing the network check in onClick function, If there is no network I want to show the same snackbar again

Comment: @VenkateswaranBalasubramanian, In `RETRY` you must add some function to check the connection that will check the connection if no connection use the same code inside that function checking network to show snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cant reshow a snackbar with an action in the snackbar. Heres an example of using a button to pop-up the snackbar. Hope it helps.

[image: MainActivity.java]

[image: activity_main.xml]

[image: Gradle.app]

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported on this. please have a look at [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200547). so until the bug fix releases you have to show another snackbar.  so total you  will have to have two snacbars. example is given below

```
private void showFirstSnackbar(View view)

        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        snackbar.dismiss();
                        showAnotherSnackBar(view);
                    }
                });
}


private void  showAnotherSnackBar(View view){
    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        snackbar.dismiss();
                        showFirstSnackbar(view);
                    }
                });
}
```

try this and let me know if there is still issues

Comment: I used only one Snackbar in a separate function. calling that function from anywhere. Now its working fine.

Comment: oh great. any how there is a bug reported.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ShowSnackBar(){
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout,"Check internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                       if(isNetworkAvailable){
                           ///called api
                         }else{
                            ShowSnackBar();
                          }
                    }
                });

 snackbar.show();      
}
if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
 ShowSnackBar();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

void ShowSnackBar(){


        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout,"Check internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        // Write Retry Code like making  api call here 

                    //    apiCall();



                    }
                });

 snackbar.show();      
}

if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
 ShowSnackBar();
}
```

Comment: may be he need this one.You may post your if you think you understood it better .....may be he want to re show snackbar I know @droidev

Comment: yes he want to show the snackbar again, but where it is written in your code ?

Comment: thank you its working now.I used this one.
  public void onClick(View view) {
     if(isNetworkAvailable){ 
         //
     }else{
        ShowSnackBar();
     }
  }

Comment: @VenkateswaranBalasubramanian Please vote it postive to show people  i get it right